# "On their back" or "on their backs"?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

> After the therapy, eight children (43%) became able to crawl/move on their back.

Or should I use "on their backs"?

Singular because each child only has one back, or plural because we're dealing with eight backs?

Comment: Related: [“Only those who qualify will be awarded a certificate” or “Only those who qualify will be awarded certificates”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/) and the many linked questions on the right hand side of this page.

Comment: I'm more puzzled by the sample size of 18.6 children.

Comment: A key aspect of this one is that elements of an experiment are *supposed* to be independent. Granularity is inherent in experimental design. Thus there were eight *separate* events of a child crawling on their back. Contrast this with a business closing causing 25 people to lose their jobs. I don't think it matters much whether the agreement issue crosses a prepositional phrase or clause boundary. The inclusion of the percentage value may well confuse the matter of event discreteness.

Comment: These constructions are often variable, the tendency to use the singular becoming more marked with more fixed phrases. _All the books you have been issued have a receipt in the back, which you must sign and hand in._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plural, because we are, in fact, dealing with eight little backs. And a back is a back, no matter how small. A child has a back, but children have backs.

I'm sure others will back me on this.

Comment: Not relevant - if several children owned a single turtle between them, it would be "their turtle", not "their turtles".

Comment: @user653: But the OP is not talking about a shared turtle.

Comment: @Robusto, I think the point @user653 was making is that the fact that "their" is plural does not automatically imply that the word following it has to be plural too.

Comment: @Hellion: Ah, I see. @user653 must be responding to @Fountain, not to my post itself.

Comment: @Robusto: also, you forgot to mention that while children have backs, baby got back.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: I'm gonna get @Martha to *thwack* you.

Comment: I mean, when "their" is used as **collections of ownership** rather than collective ownership, the noun following must be plural if countable.

Comment: I've deleted the first comment, replaced it with a clearer version. I can't edit comment after 5 mins.

Comment: This seems an uncharacteristically prescriptive position from @Robusto. Semantically/grammatically/logically plural is 'correct', but Google Books suggests that **on their back** occurs at least 10% of the time, in contravention of that logic. In my opinion there's nothing wrong with the singular, and it would be used more often if people weren't frightened of being picked up for being 'ignorant'.

Comment: @Robusto: couldn't "their" be used as a gender-neutral singular pronoun here, or I am just making that up?

Comment: This seems an uncharacteristically prescriptive position from @Robusto. I'm surprised he hasn't deleted. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou) is a better researched answer. Is Charlotte Brontë incorrect or extremely pessimistic to write 'Reader, I married him'? Must Reg Dwight's example 'Only those who qualify will be awarded a certificate' (specifying 1 apiece) be replaced by 'Only those who qualify will be awarded certificates'? (which works if there are 1, 3 or 10 apiece)?

Answer (score 5):

The semantic, grammatical, and logical arguments clearly suggest it's 'correct' to use the plural, and that's what most people do.

However, *despite* the fact that I doubt if *any* style guide endorses the singular, it seems that about [10% of usages for *back*](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=on%20their%20back,on%20their%20backs&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) persist in using the singular.

For reasons which escape me, that 'incorrect' minority rises to nearly 25% when the body part in question is *chest*. In both cases the evidence strongly suggests the incorrect usage is becoming more widespread.

Personally I believe it's a situation where grammarians backed the wrong horse, and their blind prescriptivism will eventually be defeated. People quite naturally want to use the singular when the *number of* [body parts, whatever] is immaterial, and only the *plurality of* [babies, people] is relevant. Increasingly, it seems, they're prepared to do this even at the risk of being considered illiterate.
[image: .]

Comment: Great explanation fumble. So, you are saying that it is more natural to use the singular in this case in spite of the grammatical rule, right?

Comment: In that graph, we have no idea of the surrounding context in which the words "on their chest" and "on their chests" are in. This question is about when the subject is plural.  So it is possible that people merely discuss individuals on their chest often which tilts the data when discussing plural subjects.

Comment: Try [get something off their chest / get something off their chests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+something+off+their+chest%2Cget+something+off+their+chests&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). But the distributive plural vs distributive singular question has already been well covered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: This was a while ago now, so there's no chance I can remember exactly what I was thinking when I wrote this answer! I see no evidence in my text above to suggest that I gave any serious consideration to the matter of how many of the charted instances might be *singular "they"*. But *now* I immediately think the reason the chart for ***get something off** their chest/s* looks somewhat different to the chart in my answer is probably down to the fact that *multiple people* might *have something / be* on their chest/s, but *get something **off** your chest* is usually a "solo" act.

Comment: Rappaport's analysis looks authoritative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I obviously missed your "Rappaport" answer back when it was posted - an interesting read. I guess I'm agreeing with you when I say the visitors *getting something off their **chest*** is naturally singular because it's a *figurative, universal* chest (like their singularly *toasted **health***, NOT like their plurally *blown **noses*** :)

Comment: ...but I don't know so much about *You should have seen the **expression** on their faces*. Singular ***expression*** sounds oddly "literary / poetic" to me (and I think it's stretching a point to say they all had the same expression on separate faces). I'd definitely use ***expressions*** there (and definitely forget about singular ***face***, obviously).

Comment: If they were virtually identical (eg all guilty looks), I'd use _expression_ (a common trait/property, what Rappaport labels _universal_, giving the example 'The two women toasted their health').

Answer (score 0):

It is decidedly the Singular *Back*. This is because it is the therapy that is being evaluated but the results are singular. The children are not grouped or lined up as in a race to see who can move. The plural *children* is only used to describe the percentage of those who are able to move. Each child moves only on his or her own back, no other, *Singular*.

Comment: From a logical standpoint, I would support singular, but language is not always logical. Suppose it was one child. You would still use 'their' as in "After the therapy, one child became able to crawl/move on their back". So this can clearly be the singular they/their. Dutch will use singular in this setting (for the mentioned reason in this answer), but my English feeling says 'plural'. My guess is that language is fuzzy here and that grammar professors will have a firm opinion, which may or may not reflect reality.

Comment: No. The distributive singular and distributive plural are both acceptable. In individual cases, one or the other will be more popular, but patterns are complicated (see the duplicate).