# How to close a note to more than one person and their family?

Tags: word-choice

I wrote a note addressed to more than one group. Do I close the note to you and your family or to you and your families? My memory would say either or is correct.

Comment: Clearly if it is addressed to more than one family, the correct wording would be "...to you and your families".

Comment: Thank you. To be specific, the note is addressed; Dear Mail and Delivery Personnel.

Comment: You could close with "Best wishes to you all." If it is to all personnel, they might not *have* any family, or might be recently bereaved, and being so specific is risky.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou): 'In a situation where you are speaking to a group of men — for example on a sign passed by many married men — which is correct: "Remind your wife" or "Remind your wives"?'