# Singular or plural (when referring to one occasion representing other occasions of the same kind)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Context: I am teaching an online course via WA. The teaching and learning activity is going to take place in a WA group. In that course, I need to tell my students that they will get the materials on the group one after another. So, I will not send them all at once. I will just send one material right before we are engaged in it. Can I say:
*Well, class, I will send the material you are going to learn and it should be on your phone screen while you are having it*

Comment: I will send you the material before each lesson, so that it can be on your screen during it.

Comment: You probably want to substitute _going to_ for _gonna_ if you're writing to your class (I do understand that you may have just been referring to what you might say aloud). _Gonna_ is often used when speaking, but it's not a generally accepted written form.

Comment: @WeatherVane great. What about this, *I will send you the material you are about to learn before you learn it*

Comment: @IsabelArcher okay. Sorry. :)

Comment: The phrases "about to learn" and "before you learn" are repetition of the same idea. I imagine that if you tell them you'll be sending the course material, they will understand what that means without explanation. So "I will send you the course material before each lesson" is all you need to say. Similarly if you are having a tea party, and say "I'll bring some cups" you don't have to explain "so that you have something to drink from."

Comment: @WeatherVane I see. So, it is a form of redundancy, huh? Okay, Vane, thanks a lot for the nice explanation.

Comment: @WeatherVane by the way, what if this were the situation: I will meet ten boys. Every time I am going to meet one, someone will send me a picture of the one I am going to meet. Would it be okay to say: *Someone will send me the picture of the boy I am going to meet?* I mean, would it be right to use *boy* instead of *boys* there?

Comment: Perhaps "student" will work?

Comment: @WeatherVane It's another context. It has nothing to do with the first. Should I use the singular there?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: @WeatherVane okay :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou) With your second example, _each time, someone will send me the picture of the student I am going to meet_. // Note that 'materials' in the sense you use it is plural but non-count, so you **don't** say 'I will send you four materials, one every week for a month'. 'Material' in its non-count sense might be better, in any case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it doesn't answer my question, but you did. Thanks :) one more question, what if I omitted the words *each time*, are they so important that the sentence would be considered ungrammatical without them?

Comment: 'Someone will send me the picture of the student I am going to meet.' obviously speaks of a one-off occurrence: without say 'On each occasion,' it means that it will only happen once. //  A teacher addressing a class 'Hold your protractor in place using one hand, and with your other mark the angle in pencil' is obviously speaking to more than one pupil, so is addressing the arbitrary individual within the set ('... one hand ...'). But 'Take your hands out of your pockets!' defaults to one addressee, without context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth got it. So, it is of essence to use *each* or *every* here, right? So the sentence *someone will send me a picture of **each** man I am going to meet

Comment: @EdwinAshworth edwin, please transform your comment into an answer so that I can choose it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I hardly ever 'answer' and close-vote (the 'does this answer your question?' hedge is provided with the C-V vote, and isn't how I'd assess it).