# value: singular vs plural

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

"Wall Street banks had made billions of dollars on complex investments backed by mortgages whose **value** now plunged."

In this sentence, why was the word "value" used as a singular noun here? (or is it an uncountable noun?) From what I thought, since there are multiple mortgages, values should also take a plural form, as each mortgage has a different value.

OR is it the case where the "value" was used as an uncountable noun that includes all the values of the mortgages mentioned?

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: The value of stocks has plunged. Do we have to say values? I don't think so.  It is like, "The love I get from parents, friends and relatives..." need not be 'loves.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou) ("Many of you here at this men's meeting are married. _Tell your wife you love her when you get home!_") ("Now, girls, take your protractor in your hand, and ...".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Wall Street banks had made billions of dollars on complex investments backed by mortgages whose value now plunged."
>
> In this sentence, why was the word "value" used as a singular noun here?

The singular is appropriate because each mortgage has only one value and that value has plunged on an individual basis.

"- whose value now plunged." the value **of each of which** has plunged.

Compare, "Children should not put their **head** out of the window of the train."

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is that, as you suggest, *value* encompasses the values of the countable mortgages. But this seems insufficient. If I write *covid has decreased the values of my assets* I imply that each asset (and therefore their total) has decreased. If I write *covid has decreased the value of my assets* I leave open the possibility that some have decreased, some may even have increased, and that the total has decreased.

I am no financial expert so I prudently assume ignorance of high finance and mortgages and adopt the singular version.