# Should “lifestyle” be plural here?

Tags: grammar

Should I use "their traditional lifestyles" or "their traditional lifestyle" in this sentence?

> The leaders in many Arabic countries are trying to preserve their traditional lifestyles from Western influence.

or

> The leaders in many Arabic countries are trying to preserve their traditional lifestyle from Western influence.

Are two sentences any different from each other?

Comment: Singular and plural are both fine (plural "emphasises" that there are *multiple* lifestyles, but singular doesn't necessarily imply they all share the *same* lifestyle). Compare [*Many people are turning their **back** on {something they shun}*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22many+people+are+turning+their+back+on%22)

Comment: ... 'Many people are turning their back on ...' and 'Many people are turning their backs on ...' are virtually identical in meaning. A style choice. But 'The leaders in many Arabic countries are trying to preserve their traditional lifestyle from Western influence' and 'The leaders in many Arabic countries are trying to preserve their traditional lifestyles from Western influence' strongly hint (at least) at a shared lifestyle and a variety of traditional Arabic-leader-lifestyles respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one works syntactically, but there is a semantic difference. I would ask this question: Do the leaders each have their own traditional lifestyle that differs from the others? Or do they all have basically the same shared traditional lifestyle?

Using plural "lifestyles" implies that there are various lifestyles that they want to preserve, as long as they're all traditional. Using singular "lifestyle" implies that they are interested in preserving only one (very narrow or specific) lifestyle.

Comment: Answers on ELU need substantiating references (linked and attributed); ones lacking references come over as (and may merely be) opinion, correct or not. // This is largely addressed at [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou).