# Singular or plural? into a working-class family or working-class families

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

Both Lionel Messi and Cristiano Ronaldo were born into working-class families.

Both Lionel Messi and Cristiano Ronaldo were born into a working-class family.

Comment: They were each born into a working class family, or they were both born into working class families. This assumes they are not related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of / items or people associated with individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-items-or-people-associated-with-i) ([Speaking to a large group of men] 'Remind your wife to ....' or 'Remind your wives to ....'?) Either is acceptable, as here  – though @Michael Harvey's suggestions sound more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are unrelated, the first choice sounds correct.

> Both Lionel Messi and Cristiano Ronaldo were born into working-class
> families.

If they are brother and sister or related in some way, the second makes more sense.

Comment: If they were brother and sister, pragmatics virtually demands that the relationship (whether improbable, say Shirley MacLaine and Warren Beatty, or everyday) be addressed first.