# Objectives for Plural Subjects

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

Please have a look at the following example.

1. The shops on the high street see a customer drop.
2. The shops on the high street see customer drops.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of / items or people associated with individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-items-or-people-associated-with-i)

Comment: Thanks. It is related, but this is more about the common way to express the situation. Which one would you prefer to say?

Comment: I've checked [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shops+seeing+customer+drops%2Cshops+seeing+a+customer+drop&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) and (not to my surprise) find flatlines for both 'shops seeing a customer drop' and 'shops seeing customer drops'. (Even dropping 'shops' gives zero returns.) And there seem to be no hits for the originals on Google either. I have to deduce that '**neither** is idiomatic'. 'A drop in customers' seems to outperform the more logical 'a drop in number of customers', the ratio being about 5 : 2.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but *a customer drop* is more natural.

More natural still is *a drop in customers*. I wouldn't say *customer drop*.