# How do we treat nouns that are theoretically plural but each has individuality and each belongs to a separable instance

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Context: This is a question from a Chinese high school English exam. Sorry my wording might be a little bit clumsy. Unfortunately I don't know what is the right terminology here. Please have a look at the following question to see what I mean:

> On the days in ancient times, people put ashes in the _____ (厨房）

The official answer is kitchen, singualar and the plural form is not mentioned and thus considered incorrect.

I have come across questions similar to this before and it always puzzles me. Obviously, people, as a collective entity, have more than one kitchen. But individually, each seems to own only one kitchen.

My feeling is that both kitchen and kitchens should be correct and this is merely a personal preference. I would like to know from native speakers if they will find the plural forms strange and from experts of grammar on this forum to help me understand the relavant grammar rules here, that is, if there is any rule:)

Comment: We would not, normally, use the plural unless the typical person had more than one of the object item. For instance we would say "In dry weather the people have to water the plants" because the typical person has more than one plant. However when the typical person has only one of each item (comparatively few people have more than one kitchen) the singular form is used.

Comment: The trouble with addressing such questions is that often they'd be rejected by scrutineers as containing inherent faults. No native speaker of English would use 'On the days in ancient times', and anybody using such language would be regarded as in need of basic tuition. // The question about the acceptability of 'people put ashes in the kitchen' is really about the use of what is known as the _distributive singular_. This has been answered before on ELU:...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["They're using a cell phone" vs. "They're using cell phones"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones) Or [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of 
 items or people associated with ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-items-or-people-associated-with-i) ('Remind your wife, gentlemen, that you ...')

Comment: @EdwinAshworth's comment gives a relevant and helpful duplicate. Close.