# Their house or their houses?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was correcting a piece of writing by an EFL student and wondered whether this sentence was grammatically correct:

> People are nowadays able to communicate with others from all over the world without having to leave their house.

Should it be *their house* or *their houses*, or are both acceptable?
Although it seems to be an easy question, it is difficult (if not impossible) to find a rule for it in grammar books.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["On their back" or "on their backs"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs)

Comment: Both versions occur. Plural is *probably* more common overall for all permutations of "multiple owners" of single items, and most grammarians probably recommend that. But as pointed out by my answer to the linked question, there's quite a bit of variation, at least partly depending on the specific noun. So, for example, maybe only about 10% of *people swim on their **back*** in the singular, but that might rise to more like 25% of *people with a hairy **chest***.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it could be concluded that based on descriptive grammar, the sentence written by the student is acceptable.

Comment: There’s *without leaving home,* if you want to get idiomatic about it.