# "men with older wives" or "men with an older wife"

Tags: grammatical-number

"Men with older wives" or "men with an older wife" - which is correct, or preferable, and why?

For example: "I know a lot of _______."

"Men with older wives" sounds better to me.

Both of them are, technically, ambiguous: "Men with older wives" could mean  {men, each of whom has an older wife}, or {men, each of whom has multiple older wives}. "Men with an older wife" could mean {men, each of whom has a (unique) older wife}, or {men, all of whom share an older wife}.

Comment: If you wanna be clear, don't delete so much. Assuming polygamy is not allowed (which changes the meanings), you might as well go whole hog and say what you mean - _men who have an older wife_ -- because that pushes the singular away from the plural and defines a class. If you mean to define a different class, like polygamous men with several older wives, then you can pluralize _wife_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["On their back" or "on their backs"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs). I assume the (perverse?) "polygamy" interpretation isn't really relevant (in the linked duplicate, that can't arise because each child only has ***one*** back).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. It's essentially the same question, but it doesn't seem to have a definitive answer there. By the way, may I ask, how did you find it? As in, what did you type in the search bar? I tried (unsuccessfully) to find this kind of question.

Comment: @Dan: I remembered the previous question well enough to do a (Google site-specific) search for both sequences "**their backs**" and "**their back**" (if that hadn't worked I would have switched first to **hand/s**, then **nose/s**). If by "definitive answer" you mean an answer that claims only ***one*** version is "correct", I'd say any such answer would be pedantic rubbish. The choice of plurality in such contexts is basically a stylistic choice (with a *slight* nod towards exact context and/or intended nuance, but that's not usually relevant).