# 'We are wearing a jacket' or 'we are wearing jackets'?

Tags: grammatical-number

I’m having a hard time distinguishing the following sentences. Which one is correct?

> We are wearing a jacket.

and

> We are wearing jackets.

Comment: Are you all in the same jacket?  Or does each have his or her own?

Comment: Let's say, we are wearing a different jacket.. Thank you for your quick response :)

Comment: You could say "We are wearing jackets," but, analogously to "...wearing socks," you might think each person was wearing multiple jackets (i.e. in layers).  To be accurate and also unambiguous, say "Each of us (or "Every one of us") is wearing a jacket."

Comment: Yes you're right, I think they were wearing multiple jackets  if I choose "....wearing jackets".. Thank you Steven ,for your intelligent answers!

Comment: There are two ways you can say this (1) *We are **each** wearing a jacket*. (2) *We are wearing jackets.* If you use *We are wearing a jacket,* it sounds like you are all wearing one jacket (which works if you are a king, have schizophrenia, or are two clowns, one standing on the other's shoulders.)

Comment: There's a third way too (3) We are all wearing jackets

Comment: @PeterShor Or if you're Harry, Ron, and Hermione and feeling a bit careless with your clothing terminology. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *["Those who qualify will be awarded a certificate" or "those who qualify will be awarded certificates"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6881)* Also see *[“On their back” or “on their backs”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322)*; *[“Change their positions” vs. “change their position”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80780)*, and many, many others.

Answer (score 0):

We are wearing a jacket. [incorrect unless several people are wearing just one jacket]

We are wearing jackets. [normal English]

**Example**

"What are you all wearing to the event on Tuesday?"

"We're wearing jackets and jeans."

or (!)

"We're wearing jacket and jeans."

"We're wearing jacket and tie."

That last two, without the article may be surprising and it only works because 'jacket and jeans' and 'jacket and tie' are types of outfit.